# No delivery of short string message via tcp by Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, tcp

I wanted to send simple message to the server. But I get weird exception. The code is simple but I do not understand exception.

```
 public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        sendMessage();

    }
        private void sendMessage() {
        var asyncEvent = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("192.168.0.13", 13000) };
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOEMTHING" + Environment.NewLine);
        asyncEvent.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Socket connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        connection.SendAsync(asyncEvent);
    }
```

The message is just not delivered. What do I miss?

Comment: First-chance exceptions are not necessarily a problem as you can see in [this blog post about them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx). Is your application crashing, or does the debugger pop up with the exception?

Comment: @Dirk but no message is delivered to the server. And server works... it receives TCP messages from IP camera, but does not from phone.

Comment: @Dirk And app is crashing.

Comment: @Dirk Ok I corrected the OP. Please look. No Exceptions and no delivery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the 'connect' part before sending data to the server.
Try calling ConnectAsync and then SendAsync.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the sample how to create TCP connection and send some data on Windows Phone 8